# Postman gives Cloudfront errors, but works in browser

Tags: postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

A simple HTTP GET request.

When I put the URL into the browser bar, the results come back.  (a small JSON object)

When I put the same url into Postman (https://www.postman.com/) I got the following 403 error back:

---

ERROR: The request could not be satisfied

## 403 ERROR

### The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

```
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

What is causing this and how can I use Postman on API Gateway in AWS?

As a further clue to the puzzle - when I change the request type of 'post' in postman, I get the expected response for an undefined resource: `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: Do you have the "Host" header checked on the Headers tab?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that? I am facing the same issue right now

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error and I checked the host header in the Headers tab, as user Chris suggested. That's all and the problem was solved!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34930655)

Comment: My problem was exactly the same. Checking host header in Postman as I mentioned solved the issue. Why should I do a different question and how this is not answering the question if it solved the same issue?